# What does cursor variable .delete do?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below already written code in my project. I am trying to understand what does .delete do in the below code.

```
CURSOR cur_somecur IS
select * from SomeTable;

TYPE my_cur_ty IS TABLE OF MyTable%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
my_cur     my_cur_ty;

FETCH cur_somecur BULK COLLECT
INTO my_cur LIMIT 1000;

...

LOOP

FORALL idx IN 1 .. my_cur.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS  /* This is understood */

...
my_cur.delete;   /* What does this do ? */

END LOOP;
...
```

Comment: `delete` is not a cursor variable. It is a collection method, which in your case deletes the entire collection : `my_cur`

Comment: What would happen if DELETE is not used at the end of the code? Is DELETE used to clear up some memory? Just guessing

Comment: `my_cur` is a collection (array). The name is misleading because it suggests that it has something to do with cursors, which its doesn't. You don't generally need to delete variables in PL/SQL because it does its own [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used like that, it deletes all elements from MY_CUR collection.

[Collection methods](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collection_method.htm)

> This procedure has three forms. DELETE removes all elements from a
>   collection. DELETE(n) removes the nth element from an associative
>   array or nested table. If n is null, DELETE(n) does nothing.
>   DELETE(m,n) removes all elements in the range m..n from an associative
>   array or nested table. If m is larger than n or if m or n is null,
>   DELETE(m,n) does nothing.

Comment: What would happen if DELETE is not used at the end of the code? Is DELETE used to clear up some memory? Just guessing..

Comment: Have a look at "Oracle PL/SQL Collection memory reclaim", here: http://ksun-oracle.blogspot.hr/2013/06/oracle-plsql-collection-memory-reclaim.html. It'll show you different scenarios and explain what's going on.